# Save shipping amount in quote

Tags: php, magento, quote

I've added one step after the shipping method in Magento OPC.

I need to double and save the shipping amount if the customer chooses Express shipping. How to achieve this?

What I tried:

```
1. $quote = $this->getQuote();
 $quote->setShippingAmount($price);
 $quote->setBaseShippingAmount($price);
 $quote->getShippingAddress()->collectShippingRates();
 $quote->getShippingAddress()->collectTotals();
 $quote->save();
```

Which doesn't work.

```
2.$address = $this->getQuote()->getShippingAddress();
 $method   = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getShippingMethod();

 if ($method) {
    foreach ($address->getAllShippingRates() as $rate) {
         if ($rate->getCode()==$method) {
            $amountPrice = $address->getQuote()->getStore()->convertPrice($rate->getPrice(), false);
            $method->setPrice('20');
            $method->setCost('20');
            $shippingDescription = $rate->getCarrierTitle() . ' - ' . $rate->getMethodTitle();
            $address->setShippingDescription(trim($shippingDescription, ' -'));
            break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you didn't mention about observer. so you need to create one observer to handle this things

here is very good documentation to achive your goal

just go throw [this link](http://www.danneh.org/2010/08/adding-shipping-costs-to-the-cart-automatically-in-magento/) and try to understand what they are doing. also if you want to change rate you can also it to your custom code.

hope this will sure help you.

Comment: I created an observer acc. to the instructions. But I am to update the shipping amount at the checkout step so I need some code which updates quote! I made saveQuoteBefore() method in observer and also defined it in XML properly, but I don't know what to write in it that'd save the shipping price, any idea?

Comment: if you want to use one readymade free extenstion just go throw this http://www.rapidcommerce.eu/blog/2012/04/allways-show-shipping-costs-in-magento/ and you will sure solve your issue,

Comment: is my answer is useful to you ? will pls acpt it and vote up. it would be good for future purpose if some one has same issue.

Comment: As I said, I want to save the shipping rate, and the links above do not do so. They're great but not helpful for me. I've created the extension and observer both, just want to know how to save new shipping rate in the observer.

Comment: above extension link doing same thing.it is adding selected shhiping method in quote default.

Comment: There is no cost being added there! I used the exact code but this does not work.

Comment: is your method return cost value ?

Comment: I am trying to set a static cost value first. Is there a way to update the shipping amount?

Comment: @Nitin Pant,Glad to help you.i would be appreciate if you will vote our thread so someone can trust and use our Q&A for future purpose.